# How to find all the $2 \times 2$ matrices that preserve the $\|{\cdot}\|_{\infty}$ norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I want to find all the matrices in $\mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ that satisfy $$\|Ax\|_{\infty}=\|x\|_{\infty}$$

I thought of the following. Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ and $x=(x_1,x_2)$. Then,

$$\begin{align}\|Ax\|_{\infty}=\|x\|_{\infty}&\implies\left\|\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}\right\|_{\infty}=\left\|\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}\right\|_{\infty}\\&\implies \left\|\begin{pmatrix}ax_1+bx_2\\cx_1+dx_2\end{pmatrix}\right\|_{\infty}=\left\|\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}\right\|_{\infty}\end{align}$$

I've translated what I've got into two cases:

- **Case 1:** $|ax_1+bx_2|=|x_1|$ or $|ax_1+bx_2|=|x_2|\implies a=1 ,b=0$ or $a=0 ,b=1$
- **Case 2:** $|cx_1+dx_2|=|x_1|$ or $|cx_1+dx_2|=|x_2|\implies c=1 ,d=0$ or $c=0,d=1$

If these cases are correct how can I construct the matrices based on these conditions?

Comment: Shouldn't case 1 be $a=\pm1, b=0$ or $a=0, b=\pm1$?

Answer (score 1):

You are more or less on the right track, but the analysis is not quite correct. E.g. you haven't taken into account the possibility that some of $a,b,c,d$ are negative.

Anyway, I think it is more natural to solve the problem geometrically. For instance, consider the square $\|x\|_\infty=1$. You may try to prove that $A$ maps extreme points onto extreme points (that is, $A$ maps the four corners $(\pm1,\pm1)$ onto themselves), and also that it maps opposite sides of the square onto opposite sides of the square. Then you can use linearity to conclude that there are only $2^4$ choices of $A$, namely, $\pmatrix{a\\ &d}$ or $\pmatrix{&b\\ c}$, where $|a|=|b|=|c|=|d|=1$. This may not result in a simpler approach than yours, but I believe it's easier for one to understand what's going on.